# Creating an exclusion for *.domain.com for multiple code directories for multiple subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, domains

I have an IIS server (on win2008 server) with a website on it, serving multiple subdomains using a website *.domain.com

Theres not a defined list, subdomains could be anything.

All of these requests are served from a specific code directory, lets call it app1

I want to make changes such that:

subdomains sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com so that they serve code from a different application app2.

all other subdomains should continue to be served from the original app1 code.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sub domains, then I'd have a different site (call it site 2) pointing to app1, put the certain domains as host-headers with the same ip address as the other unknown on a separate site that has ip address bindings (call it site 1).

When you want to update code for site 2, update the folder location to app2 on site2 with the host-headers.  If you have multiple servers, I would take one out of load, update to your needs, put in load and continue with other boxes.

Hope that helps.